# bootstrap 4 navbar button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello everyone i have problem with bootstrap navbar maybe is something simple but i was fighting 2 days alone and at the last i give up. I dont know where is problem but my menu is not working well, I see the button instead of the menu, if i wanna see menu i must press the button. Thanks a lot for help i appreciated every answer. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8dyN.jpg)

```css
nav{
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999 !important;



}
a{
  outline-color: rgb(232, 127, 6);
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: linear;

}
img{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  float: right;
}
.menu ul{
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li a {
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  display: block;
  font-family: "Ovo";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 37px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
  padding-top: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  text-decoration-line: none;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-6 pull-right">
            <div class="menu poki-menu-wrapper">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse" >
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
                <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
                  <ul>
                      <li id="menu-item-01" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-01"><a class="active" href="home">Home</a></li>
                      <li id="menu-item-02" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-02"><a href="aboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                      <li id="menu-item-03" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-03"><a href="map">Map</a></li>
                      <li id="menu-item-04" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-04"><a href="export">Export</a></li>
                      <li id="menu-item-05" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-05"><a href="menu-5">menu-item-05</a></li>
                      <li id="menu-item-06" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-06"><a href="contact">Contact</a><li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Why do you think you don't see the button, based on the way you code? Have you read through `bootstrap` documentation?

Comment: what documentation you mean ?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Comment: I find solution problem was with ''Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.'' I was had break with coding in bootstrap 3 was difrent. Thanks a lot.